# Cannot get values from Lark AST

Tags: python-3.7, lark-parser

I cannot and do not know how to retrieve the values of an AST that I generated using the Lark parser.

My grammar is as follows, saved in a .lark file :

```
start: (un_handle ": ")? AMOUNT "|" p_handle ("," p_handle)* (" \"" MESSAGE* "\"")?

AMOUNT: /[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?/

un_handle: HANDLE

p_handle: HANDLE

HANDLE : /[A-Z][A-Z]/

MESSAGE : /[^"]+/
```

I then run:

```
testText = '10|GP "Bananas"'
testTree = parser.parse(testText)
```

and get:

```
Tree(start, [Token(AMOUNT, '10'), Tree(p_handle, [Token(HANDLE, 'GP')]), Token(MESSAGE, 'Bananas')])
```

But, what now?

I realize that I have to probably have to build a transformer, but what methods should I define and what should I call them? I just want to extract the values for AMOUNT, un_handle, p_handle (there may be more than one p_handle), and message into   Python variables.

Thank you so much in advance! Have been debugging for hours.

Comment: You can just call your methods `p_handle`, `un_handle`, `start`, etc. What difficulty are you having with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, try adding a "line" rule to provide a reference point. Yes, your application does not probably use multiple lines, but it is usually good to include one just in case.

Now, write a subroutine to find each "line" token in the AST, and append it to a list.

Finally, I suggest that you process the resulting list using a subroutine based upon the `eval()` subroutine in [LisPy](http://norvig.com/lispy.html).